# rails devise after_sign_up_path_for undefined method `subdomain'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, apartment-gem

I am attempting to redirect user after successfully signing up to their respective subdomain. I have input the following code within the application_controller.

application_controller.rb

```
protected

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  redirect_to root_url(subdomain: @users.subdomain)
end
```

I am receiving the following error

```
NoMethodError in Devise::SessionsController#create
undefined method `subdomain' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #10):


def after_sign_up_path_for(subdomain)
  redirect_to root_url(subdomain: @users.subdomain)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> NoMethodError in Devise::SessionsController#create undefined method
>   `subdomain' for nil:NilClass

`@users` is `nil`, so Rails spits out with that error. As you are using Devise, the *Devise model(`User`) instance* can be accessed with `resource`.

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  redirect_to root_url(subdomain: resource.subdomain)
end
```

You can also use `current_user`

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  redirect_to root_url(subdomain: current_user.subdomain)
end
```